# OllyDbg. Как убрать MessageBox при запуске программы?

Tags: reverse-engineering

Всем привет.
Изучаю реверс-инженеринг. Попался такой "CrackMe" в котором при запуске вылазает   MessageBox с сообщением "remove me". Как его убрать? Помогите. Вроде бы нашел функцию MessageBox. нашел текст "remove me" в коде. Но при поставке точки останова он не останавливается. Распишите по "1. ... 2. ... 3. ..." а дальше сам разберусь.
Программа написана на VB

Comment: Тема слишком объёмная для ответа на этом сайте. Если это vb6, то все довольно геморно (если это vb.net, то вы вообще не сможете его отлаживать с помощью ollydbg). Лучше начинать с crackme написанных на чистом Си или Ассемблере.

Comment: @insolor Я чекал FileDetector, это Visual Basic обычный. Насчёт .NET я знаю. У меня есть DotPeek. Но всё же можете максимально кратко описать? Я сам найду инфу. Просто нашел пак 16 CrackMe уже 5 пропатчил. И еще вопросик, если не против - можете подсказать как включить кнопку какую то? К примеру она серая и на неё нельзя нажать, нужно её вернуть что бы можно было на неё нажать.

Comment: Максимально кратко вы и так скорее всего знаете - найти функцию, поставить брекпоинт, отловить срабатывание, пропатчить условие. Остальное в одном ответе не уместишь. Разблокировать кнопку - посмотрите здесь программы: [Программы для работы с окнами приложений](http://www.manhunter.ru/underground/1035_programmi_dlya_raboti_s_oknami_prilozheniy.html). Я когда-то пользовался InqSoft Window Scanner, он там есть.

Comment: @insolor Афигеть! Спасибо! Я крч сидел думал, думал, расставил брекпоинты, потом вижу: "CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&MSVBVM60.__vbaFreeV", прочитал, и афигел! Как же всё легко! Просто заполнил нопами и messagebox больше не срабатывал. Но что то я сомневаюсь что это правильное решение, или всё таки правильное?

Comment: @insolor А без постороннего ПО, только с Olly можно? Или можно так-же отловить функцию и стереть нопами? (пишу перед запуском Olly)

Comment: Зависит от того как окно создается и как кнопка блокируется. Например, если блокируется функцией [`EnableWindow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow), то нужно отловить эту функцию. Может Но кнопка может быть создана изначально заблокированной. Куча вариантов в общем. По поводу правильности решения - бывает по-разному.